Reference for representation theory over the reals
I want a book with details about real representation theory, specifically about the projections onto isotypic components.
Let $(V,\rho)$ be a $G$-representation over field $\mathbb{F}$. Let $W_i$ be irreducible representations over $\mathbb{F}$ with character $\chi_{W_i}$. Suppose $V \cong \bigoplus_i W_i^{n_i}$. In so many textbooks, I have seen $$\frac{\dim(W_i)}{|G|}\sum_i\chi_{W_i}(g^{-1})\rho_g$$ is a projection of $V$ onto the isotypic component $W_i^{n_i}$ when $\mathbb{F}$ is the field of complex numbers or more generally a splitting field of characteristic zero for $G$. However, I have not seen any extension of this projection when $\mathbb{F}$ is the field of real numbers. Do you know any book, article, or paper that talked about the projection of real representations onto their isotypic components? or anything that talked about central idempotents in real group algebra $\mathbb{R}G$.
I have seen different textbooks but could not find anything.
"Linear Representations of Finite Groups" by Serre contains the complex case. While it talks about the real case, it does not have anything on the projections or central idempotents for the real case. "Representation Theory: A First Course" by Fulton and Harris has a similar situation." Representation Theory of Finite Groups and Associative Algebras" by Curtis-Reiner contains central idempotents for splitting fields for $G$ but not for my case. "Algebra" by Lang has details for representations over any field extension, though it does not talk about projections and central idempotents in the real case. "Methods of Representation Theory: With Applications to Finite Groups and Orders" by Curtis and Reiner seems completer than the other mentioned books. However, it does not have any formula based on characters of $W_i$ for the projections or central idempotents of $\mathbb{R}G$ or, at least, I could not find one.

I don't think I understand what goes wrong with the usual idempotent proof of this, for example in lemma 15.12 of Isaacs's Algebra.

This follows more or less directly from the orthogonality relations so we just have to understand how the orthogonality relations generalize to the case that we aren't working over a splitting field. Let $K$ be a field of characteristic zero for simplicity (we will need to divide by some stuff later). Maschke's theorem continues to hold. Schur's lemma here implies that if $\{ V_i \}$ are the irreducible representations of $G$ over $K$, then
$$\dim \text{Hom}_G(V_i, V_j) = \delta_{ij} \dim D_i$$
where $D_i = \text{End}_G(V_i)$ is the endomorphism algebra of $V_i$, which is a finite-dimensional division algebra over $K$. The special feature of the non-split case is that $D_i$ can be strictly larger than $K$. It is still true in the non-split case that the projection from a representation $V$ to its fixed points $V^G$ is given by $\frac{1}{|G|} \sum_{g \in G} \rho_V(g)$, so $\dim V^G$ is given by the trace of this projection, and so it is still true that
$$\dim \text{Hom}_G(V_i, V_j) = \frac{1}{|G|} \sum_{g \in G} \chi_i(g^{-1}) \chi_j(g)$$
where $\chi_i$ is the character of $V_i$. Combining these two identities we conclude that the orthogonality relations over $K$ read
$$\langle \chi_i, \chi_j \rangle = \frac{1}{|G|} \sum_{g \in G} \chi_i(g^{-1}) \chi_j(g) = \delta_{ij} \dim D_i.$$
When $K = \mathbb{R}$ the division algebras $D_i$ can $\mathbb{R}, \mathbb{C}$, or $\mathbb{H}$, which correspond to the possible values $\dim D_i = 1, 2, 4$.
Now we can write down the projections to the isotypic components as follows. We want to write down elements of the group algebra with the following properties:

They should be central. This happens exactly if the coefficients are invariant under conjugation, which is in particular guaranteed if the coefficients are built from a character.
By Schur's lemma, central elements act by an element of $D_i$ on $V_i$. We want to write down central elements which act by $1$ on a fixed irreducible representation and $0$ on all other irreducible representations. (It follows without an explicit calculation that such an element is idempotent.)

The orthogonality relations imply that the central element $\frac{1}{|G|} \sum_{g \in G} \chi_i(g^{-1}) g$ acts with trace $\delta_{ij} \dim D_i$ on $V_j$. Edit: Previously there was a gap in the argument here, as pointed out by khashayar. What we would like to know is that this element acts by a scalar in $K$, rather than just by a "scalar" in $D_i$. I think the "right" way to do this is to consider the trace over $D_i$ but I'm not sure what the details look like.
An alternative approach, which suffices for our purposes but which is a little unsatisfying to me, is to pass to the algebraic closure $\overline{K}$. After extension of scalars, each irreducible $V_j$ breaks up into a direct sum of irreducibles over $\overline{K}$. $\frac{1}{|G|} \sum_{g \in G} \chi_i(g^{-1}) g$ acts by a scalar in $\overline{K}$ on each of these irreducibles, which the orthogonality relations (over $\overline{K}$) tell us has trace an integer, and hence which is rational. So $\frac{1}{|G|} \sum_{g \in G} \chi_i(g^{-1}) g$ also acts by a rational scalar on the extension of scalars $V_j \otimes_K \overline{K}$, and hence on $V_j$ itself, with trace $\delta_{ij} \dim D_i$. This scalar must therefore be $\delta_{ij} \frac{\dim D_i}{\dim V_i}$, or equivalently $\frac{\delta_{ij}}{\dim_{D_i} V_i}$. It follows that the desired projection to the isotypic component of $V_i$ is
$$\boxed{ \frac{\dim_{D_i} V_i}{|G|} \sum_{g \in G} \chi_i(g^{-1}) g }.$$
Probably the restriction to characteristic zero is not necessary; if we knew some result along the lines that $\dim_{D_i} V_i$ always divides $|G|$ then it ought to suffice for $K$ to have characteristic not dividing $|G|$, the usual condition for Maschke's theorem to continue to hold. Even without knowing anything special about the divisibility properties of $\dim_{D_i} V_i$ it's clear that $\dim V_i \le |G|$, say (this is not sharp), so we get the result for $K$ having characteristic larger than $|G|$.

"By Schur's lemma, central elements act by a scalar on an irreducible representation." Should not this be true only for splitting field for $G$?  if $D_i$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$, then everything is fine. However, if $D_i$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{C}$, why do not central elements act like $a I + b J$, where $I$ is the identity and $J$ is an involution? or if $D_i$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{H}$, why are not central elements of the form $a I + b J + c K +d L$, where $I$ is the identity and $J,\ K,\ L$ are involutions?

@khashayar: ah, my apologies, you're right, I've been sloppy. The correct statement is that a central element always acts by a "scalar" in $D_i$, not necessarily in $K$. So we actually need to work over $D_i$ and take traces over $D_i$ to conclude. Let me think about how this works.

@khashayar: I've now fixed the argument.

The reason that I asked this question is to be able to answer this other question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4930009/further-decomposition-of-isotypic-components-in-a-representation      It seems I cannot use second argument to generalize it to my purpose. But maybe I can answer my question with your first argument. Would you please check my other question

I have finally found the book that contains the central primitive idempotent of the group algebra $KG$ for any field $K$ such that $|G| \in K^{\times}$ with the detailed proof. Here is the book and the related theorem:
Theorem 3, Chapter 33 of
Algebra Volume II: Fields with Structure, Algebras, and Advanced Topics (by Falko Lorenz, 2008)
